# Problems with navbar height

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Please, look at this sample template: http://jsfiddle.net/D8cye/2/

As you can see, the `navbar` expands to the bottom of the sidebar. Why? How can I avoid this?

I know I can workaround this by setting `.navbar-inner{height:40px;}`. But I feel that I'm doing something wrong of perhaps I have misunderstood something with the fluid grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forked it here http://jsfiddle.net/Astraldiva/r6tHv/.

I think that one of the important things to consider while using twitter bootstraps fluid layout is not to have items with fixed width or the layout will brake. Not sure if this helps but I just rearranged the containers and placed the content in span8 + span4 divs to get  similar layout like you wanted and this version should work on different screen sizes.

```
 <div class=row-fluid>
    <div class=span8>
        <div id=text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class=navbar>
            <div class=navbar-inner>
                <ul class=nav>
                    <li class=active><a href=#>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Link</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class=span4>
        <div class=box></div>
        <div class=box></div>
        <div class=box></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

To get the wanted layout [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/175975/peter) made an extension on my idea [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D8cye/9/).

There is a 2 column layout, a fixed with sidebar and fluid content area (with max and min width). So it's not completely fluid but solves the problem.

```
<div id=container>
    <!-- Sidebar is floated right and has fixed width -->
    <div id=side>
        <div class=box></div>
        <div class=box></div>
        <div class=box></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Content wrapper is in normal flow with margin-right of at least the width of a sidebar-->
    <div id=main>
        <div class=row-fluid>
          <div class=span12>
            <div id=text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>

            <div class=navbar>
                <div class=navbar-inner>
                    <ul class=nav>
                        <li class=active><a href=#>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href=#>Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
border: 1px solid #f00;
max-width: 600px;
min-width: 300px;
}

#side {
float: right;
width: 100px;
border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

#main {
margin-right: 108px;
border: 1px solid #00f;
}

#text {
padding: 8px; margin: 8px; border: 1px solid #888;
}

.box {
height: 80px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
background: #ddd;
}
```

Note: twitter bootstrap css included.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that I need a fixed-width sidebar (to place ads and other fixed width content). But I can't use the fixed grid because it's limited to 960px. What I want to do is a maxwidth:1200px, minwidth:900px website with a fixed-width sidebar and fluid content. Shouldn't be too complicated. :S

Comment: You directed me to the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/D8cye/9/ Now there's a fluid content, with fixed sidebar and the navbar works fine. 
If you edit your answer to reflect this I will approve it.

Comment: Was just working on a very similar example :> That's the approach I would take to get the result you want. Glad you worked it out. Will make an edit now. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;` for `.navbar-inner` like this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/D8cye/4/)

Explanation: using `display: inline-block;` won't take up the extra space which your navigation bar was using before, horizontally as well as vertically... :)

CSS

```
.navbar-inner {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Edit: If you want your navigation menu to be 100% of width than do it like this

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/D8cye/7/)

CSS

```
.navbar-inner {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: But now, the width of the navbar doesn't fills the container width.

Comment: @Peter check out the second demo

Comment: This is weird. Don't you think so? We shouldn't been using workarounds or hacks to implement such simple tasks with a framework.

Comment: @Peter It was weird indeed...never worked with bootstrap just applied normal CSS rule

Comment: I'm going to wait a little before approving your answer to see if somebody gives another answer. Perhaps I'm using bootstrap in a wrong way.